# How to display more than 3 items in a row?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem displaying a portfolio on my site. I would like to display more than 3 in row, like [here](http://www.podsluchyonline.pl).

Is there any easy CSS command to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Simply change the width of the `li` elements to something smaller or equal to 25%.

```
.home-section ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5.63%;
    width: 20%;  /*changed this value*/
```